# Idiom for strict typedef in C++

Tags: c++, templates, types, idioms

Is there an idiom for a strict typedef in C++, possibly using templates?

Something like:

```
template <class base_type, int N> struct new_type{
    base_type p;
    explicit new_type(base_type i = base_type()) : p(i) {}
};

typedef new_type<int, __LINE__> x_coordinate;
typedef new_type<int, __LINE__> y_coordinate;
```

So I can make something like this a compile time error:

```
x_coordinate x(5);
y_coordinate y(6);

x = y; // whoops
```

The `__LINE__` in there looks like it might be trouble, but I'd prefer not to have to manually create a set of constants merely to keep each type unique.

Comment: Coordinates are not a very good application for this. A product of two coordinates is not a coordinate, etc. You may want to look at Boost.Units instead.

Comment: I deleted my answer which suggested [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html), because apparently that works for overload resolution but does not generate compilation errors on cross-assignment.

Comment: I question the value of what you want to do. What happens when you want to perform a rotation for example? `x = sin(theta)*y + cos(theta)*x` should be entirely valid.

Comment: this is mostly needed for base_type == int, but if casting to/from int are provided, the whole purpose is lost. The solution is to provide only either 'to' or 'from' casting, and do the other side using a fn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using something similar in my project. Only I use type tagging instead of int. Works well in my particular application.

```
template <class base_type, class tag> class new_type{     
  public:   
    explicit new_type(base_type i = base_type()) : p(i) {}

    //
    // All sorts of constructors and overloaded operators
    // to make it behave like built-in type
    //

  private:
     base_type p;
};

typedef new_type<int, class TAG_x_coordinate> x_coordinate;
typedef new_type<int, class TAG_y_coordinate> y_coordinate;
```

Note that TAG_* classes don't need to be defined anywhere, they are just tags

```
x_coordinate x (1);
y_coordinate y (2);

x = y; // error
```

Comment: I think this would look nicer with a simple "#define new_type(base, tag) typedef new_type<##base, class TAG_##tag> tag;"

Comment: @slacy dunno, I find macros ugly and avoid them

Comment: Macros aren't just ugly; they also cause problems due to not obeying scope. They're a last resort for me. (If you want to use it for something like this, consider using `#undef` afterwards. However, this can cause other problems if someone else defined that macro because you'll undefine theirs. So then you want to check to make sure no one else defined a macro by the same name. Etc. etc.)

Answer (score 2):

No. There are proposals for it to go into the next standard (C++14, or perhaps C++17), but not in C++11.

Comment: -1: He didn't ask whether it's in the language, and there _are_ ways to do it in "user space". Therefore, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: There are no ways to do it in user space that are the same as the language feature being proposed.

Comment: What about that are the same as what is stated in the question? Now that Angew's answer has been invalidated I am open to the possibility, but require your input here.

Comment: Because the new_type doesn't actually behave like it's original type in many scenarios. For example, you can't do `new_type<std::string, ...>().c_str();`.

Comment: @Puppy The question doesn't mention C++11 specifically, but I see your answer was written in 2013. Would you consider updating it? (Did something make it in?)

Answer (score 0):

With C++11:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dummy {};

struct NotMineType
{
    NotMineType(dummy) {}
};

template <int N>
struct type_scope
{
    struct MyOwnType
    {
    };

    struct ConvertedToMineType : NotMineType
    {
        template <typename ...Args>
        ConvertedToMineType(Args... args) : NotMineType(args...) {};
    };

    enum myint : int {};
};

typedef type_scope<0>::MyOwnType x1;
typedef type_scope<1>::MyOwnType x2;

typedef type_scope<0>::ConvertedToMineType y1;
typedef type_scope<1>::ConvertedToMineType y2;

typedef type_scope<0>::myint i1;
typedef type_scope<1>::myint i2;

void foo(x1) { printf("x1\n"); }
void foo(x2) { printf("x2\n"); }
void foo(y1) { printf("y1\n"); }
void foo(y2) { printf("y2\n"); }
void foo(i1) { printf("i1\n"); }
void foo(i2) { printf("i2\n"); }

int main()
{
    foo(x1());
    foo(x2());
    foo(y1(dummy()));
    foo(y2(dummy()));
    foo(i1());
    foo(i2());
}
```

**Output:**

```
x1
x2
y1
y2
i1
i2
```

**Compilers:**

Visual Studio 2015, GCC 4.8.x